# Tag chef node based on specific attributes

Tags: chef-infra

When you run the following command and get its output:

```
$ knife node show webnode21.domain.tld -a openstack
webnode21.domain.tld:
  openstack:
    ami_id:                      ami-88171711
    ami_launch_index:            0
    ami_manifest_path:           /var/os/manifest
    block_device_mapping_ami:    vdb
    block_device_mapping_ebs0:   /dev/vdb
    block_device_mapping_root:   /dev/vdb
    block_device_mapping_swap:   /dev/vdc
    hostname:                    webnode21.domain.tld
    instance_action:             none
    instance_id:                 i-11243010
    instance_type:               small
    local_hostname:              webnode21.domain.tld
    local_ipv4:                  192.168.20.101
    placement_availability_zone: AZ002
    provider:                    openstack
    public_hostname:             webnode21.domain.tld
    public_ipv4:
    public_keys_0_openssh_key:   ssh-rsa somekey
    reservation_id:              r-88x801h
    security_groups:             default
```

I'd like to be able to tag the following attributes inside a recipe: hostname, ami_id, security_groups, local_ipv4. I know you can tag using tag('key:value') .. but I'm not sure how to go about pulling the attributes in the recipe and only tagging specific key/value pairs.

Comment: Do you mean Chef's node tags or AWS object tags?

Comment: @coderanger Not necessarily. I know about the AWS Ohai plugin.. this is attributes I want to use in a recipe to tag chef nodes with. So, this node would have tags like: Tags: hostname:webnode21.domain.tld, ami_id:ami-88171711, local_ipv4:192.168.20.101, security_groups:default.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what Chef "tags" are, it's just an array in the node attributes (and notably are not k/v pairs, just strings). The things you showed are already node attributes so they wouldn't make any sense to use with the tags "system" (again, it's just an array of strings in the node attrs).

Comment: Thanks. But I like to tag the nodes in such way to use those tags in external applications for statistical and querying purposes. Will you be able to help with that?

Comment: Why? You can just use the existing attributes for all the searches you need.

Comment: If I wanted to do that, I would. Thanks for the useful answers.

Comment: This might be best handled in the Chef Slack, http://community-slack.chef.io/. You mention stuff like using `foo:bar` in Chef node tags which is not part of the normal pattern so I need a better understanding of your use case to advise on the right direction.

Comment: MikeD: note that @coderanger isn't the only one reading your comments, and from where I sit, I don't see why anyone would be motivated to "help" you as you appear to be lashing out at someone who is obviously knowledgeable and disposed to help you if you let him.

Comment: Explain this, at what point does it appear that mr coderanger is actually making an attempt to answer my question? A question that I just figured out the answer to myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, finally. Posting answer in case anyone else comes across something like this:

```
if node['openstack']['ami_id']
  tag("ami_id:#{node['openstack']['ami_id']}")
end
```